# Who was Chrono waving to at the wedding?

Tags: chrono-trigger

in the Ending Cinematic of *Chrono Trigger* (i'm playing the DS Version), when Chrono and Marle are walking down the aisle a man pushes his way through the crowd to reach the front and the scene focuses on him before going back to Chrono and Marle were we see Chrono wave

[image: Unknown man][image: Chrono Waving]

Who is this man?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Pixel art of Melchior]
That's Melchior, one of the three gurus.

You might remember him from the Millenial Fair, where he sells some starter gear at the beginning of the game. Later on, he helps Chrono and the gang to reforge the Masamune. He also plays a part in the Antiquity storyline.

The [Chronopedia](http://chrono.wikia.com/wiki/Melchior) also mentions his appearance in the ending:

> Melchior appears in the ending after you defeat Lavos. Melchior comes to Crono, and Marle's wedding with a bottle. Crono and Marle notice him because they wave back.